# Set variable to the name of the module that has imported it

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.7

Assume I have two modules:

**first.package.module**

```
# Assign module to a variable
which_module = ???

print("I originally live in {}".format(__name__))   # Prints first.package.module
print("I was run from {}".format(which_module))
```

**second.package.module**

```
from first.package.module import *
```

**third.package.module**

```
from first.package.module import *
```

How can I get the second row, "I was run from", to print *second.package.module* after the import in second.package.module? Or *third.package.module* when it is run from there.

The reason I want this behaviour is due to building an app in Django that is used several times in the same project, i.e. there are several instances of the same app. Each of these instances has their own models, which inherits from an abstract model. To build reusable views and urls, I want to load the models dynamically, and to do that, I need to know which module that has imported the app and runs it.

Comment: Why do you need that? What problem are you trying to solve that requires you to look up the frame stack to see what imported you first?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I tried to explain it in the end of the post. I have a Django app that I use multiple times in the same project. Each instance of the app has its own model. So, to write a reusable version of urls and views, I need to know which instance is being worked on, so I dynamically can load the corresponding model.

Comment: Why not just pass in a parameter when creating the urls and models? Or use a Django configuration variable? Your code is run only **once** when imported, so if you are this in the same Django process you cannot even do what you want.

Comment: I've tried, but can't come up with a good way on how to solve it. I guess it's possible to wrap something around everything (urlpatterns, for example) that generates the things using a variable, but then I also loose the simplicity of just star-importing everything.

Answer (score 3):

You can print the name of the module triggering the module load with:

```
import sys

print sys._getframe(1).f_globals['__name__']
```

In Python 3 with the new `importlib` stack you'll need to increase the framecount to 6 (at least for 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7):

```
print(sys._getframe(6).f_globals['__name__'])
```

A cross-CPython solution would be to filter out any `importlib._bootstrap*` elements in the stack:

```
import sys

def imported_from(depth=0):
    # skip the frames of this function, and the caller
    f = sys._getframe(2 + depth)
    while f and f.f_code.co_filename.startswith("<frozen importlib._bootstrap"):
        f = f.f_back
    return f and f.f_globals['__name__']

print(imported_from())
```

The above `imported_from()` function can be defined in a utility module and imported; the `sys._getframe(2)` call ensures that the starting context is whatever triggered the `imported_from()` call. Provide a positive integer as the `depth` argument to increase the number of frames skipped. The function works on any Python version that provides a `sys._getframe()` function, whether or not it uses the `importlib` stack.

Note that this:

- Relies on a CPython implementation detail (exposing the frame stack is not available on other Python implementations). See the [`sys._getframe()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys._getframe):

  > **CPython implementation detail**: This function should be used for internal and specialized purposes only. It is not guaranteed to exist in all implementations of Python.
- In Python 3, it depends on the exact implementation details of the `importlib` stack; ongoing development could add or remove calls in that stack. For example, in Python 3.3, which first introduced `importlib`, the correct stack count to skip is 9, in 3.4 it went down to 7, and 3.5 dropped it to 6 (a number that's since been stable). `imported_from()` works around this, but introduces a new implementation detail-dependent assumption: that the stack frames involved with importing can be detected by looking for the `<frozen importlib._bootstrap` prefix in the filename. In theory it is possible to compile CPython with `importlib._bootstrap` left un-frozen (not included in the interpreter binary as array of `marshal` data).
- Only works when a module is imported for the first time, at which point Python executes the module code to produce a `sys.modules` object.

I cannot emphasise the last point enough. Python only ever loads a module **once**. Importing is a two-step process: loading and binding. The load step is only executed if the module object doesn't exist yet, all other imports for the module *only bind names*.

Binding names is not something you can practically hook into; `import modulename` is nothing more than a `modulename = sys.modules['modulename']` assignment once the module is already in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This, however, only gives me *importlib._bootstrap*.

Comment: @ChristofferKarlsson: in Python 3 you'll have to increase the frame count.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think this will help me enough though. As you wrote, "Only works when a module is imported for the first time". I import it in multiple files and need to know which one imported it. Updated question.

Comment: @ChristofferKarlsson: as I stated already: *you can't*. That's not how Python imports work. Python loads the code just once, then binds names from the loaded object. It will not re-execute your code for each import statement.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I guess I have to find another way of solving this then.

Comment: Can the number 6 be relied upon? That is to say, is there any case in CPython 3 where the 6th frame up won't be from the importing module?

Comment: @M.I.Wright: it is entirely dependent on the current version implementation details, so no. But it is the right number for Python 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7.

Comment: @M.I.Wright: I updated the answer to emphasise this.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Guess I'll loop through `inspect.stack()` should I ever need to use this seriously...